# What should be canonical of mobile website?

Tags: canonical-url, mobile, rel-canonical

We have two versions, mobile & desktop with URLs:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/m/
```

What should be canonical of `http://example.com/m/` web page? Should it have canonical as `http://example.com/m/` OR its canonical should point to its desktop version i.e. `http://example.com/`?

Comment: In 2018 Google will [index and rank first the mobile version](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-mobile-first-indexing-what-it-is-how-you-can-prepare/212104/) of the website, meaning the mobile version is what they evaluate and score, not the desktop, so technically canonical should point to the [mobile version](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/mobile-first-indexing.html) but with that said Google said back last year that it wasn't required. Personally and if possible I would drop the `/m/` version altogether and go responsive, not req but my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

According to **[Google search guides Separate URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)**:

> On the desktop page, add a special link **rel=”alternate”** tag pointing    to the corresponding mobile URL. This helps Googlebot discover the    location of your site’s mobile pages. `<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
>    href="http://example.com/m">`
>
> On the mobile page, add a link **rel=”canonical”** tag pointing to the corresponding desktop URL. `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/">`